# TRIM Trailing Zeros

Tags: sql, oracle, trim

I know this is a relatively simple question, but I couldn't find anything with my keywords using Google.
I am referencing with a SQL (Oracle) to a column that has numbers like that:

- 100
- 12500
- 300

Now I need to remove the last 2 zeros. 
This approach is not working:

```
Trim(TRAILING '00' FROM F0035.Nr)         "Sequence",
```

Does anyone have any idea?

The result should be a column with numbers - not a text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these two options:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '100'   from dual union all
  3     select '12500' from dual union all
  4     select '300'   from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7    to_number(substr(col, 1, length(col) - 2)) result_1,
  8    to_number(col) / 100 result_2
  9  from test;

COL     RESULT_1   RESULT_2
----- ---------- ----------
100            1          1
12500        125        125
300            3          3

SQL>
```

- the first one removes the last two characters (from your sample data, it seems that they are always `00`)
- the second one divides that "number" by `100`

Comment: Thanks! The first one works perfectly. The deviation by 100 will not work for values like 150. This would present not a whole number how it actually is.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(F0035.Nr, '^(.*)00$', '\1')
FROM F0035
```

You can easily tweak the regular expression if your requirements change subtly, such as removing more than 2 trailing zeros (e.g. `^(.*)00+`), or other characters

Answer (score 1):

```
with test (col) as (
  select 10   from dual union all
  select 100  from dual union all
  select 1000 from dual union all
  select 12500 from dual union all
  select 125002 from dual union all
  select 3000   from dual
)
select col, 
case when substr(col, -2) = '00' then col/100 else col end newnum
from test;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the column contains numbers, why are you using string operations?

If all values have two 00s as the end, then:

```
F0035.Nr / 100
```

If some do not, then use a `case`:

```
(case when mod(F0035.Nr, 100) = 0 then F0035.Nr / 100 else F0035.Nr end)
```

I don't recommend converting to a string to do numeric operations under most circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. Why you don't recommend doing numeric operations for strings?

Comment: @joshua . . . SQL has types for a reason.  Strings and numbers are different beasts.  In addition, such constructs in a `where` or `on` clause pretty much kill the optimizer.  Plus, I have wasted an inordinate amount of time debugging queries (mine and other people's) caused by implicit conversion errors.

Answer (score 1):

The following expression will strip off any number of zeroes from a number:

```
SELECT NR / POWER(10, LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(NR), '0*$')))
  FROM F0035
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0999fb71ce96935200410f04b9a15cbb)